# Create an MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, request

I have a table like this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/052381/1

I need to create a request that will find VIN codes that meet the following conditions:

1. VIN starts with XTA%
2. I have registration history: date_reg_last values: 1306440000,1506715200,1555963200. You need to select only those VIN codes that have exactly these values. If there are more or less records - VIN does not match
3. I have an owner_type that matches the values ​​1306440000,1506715200,1555963200: 2, 2, 2. Ie. for record 1306440000 owner_type must be 2, for record 1506715200 also 2, etc. The type can be different for each entry.
4. Similarly to the third point, I have regions: УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.,УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.,С РУНГА
5. I have a year, it should be in all records.

I tried making a request like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ac_gibdd_shortinfo` 
WHERE `vin` LIKE 'XTA%' 
  AND `model` LIKE '%1119%' 
  AND `date_reg_first` IN (0,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `date_reg_last` IN (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `year` LIKE '2011' 
  AND `location` IN ('УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.','С РУНГА')
```

But it finds records that have a different number of registration records. There is only one thought: get all the matching records and then filter them by number with an additional request.

Comment: `model` LIKE '%1119%' appears in the query but not in the list of requirements?

Comment: *If there are more or less records - VIN does not match* Do you mean that if there are 2 rows for particular VIN, one of them with the date from the list and another with the date not  from the list then none of these rows must be returned? PS. Show desired output for fiddle data.

Comment: P.Salmon, sorry, I forgot add this condition. But this is a simple condition and I don't have a problem with this.

@Akina, you are correct.
Final list need contains only this VIN: XTA111930B0149393 and have a 3 record with id: 38483146, 98294552 and 112853476

Comment: Does `date_reg_last` is the only column with such restriction?

Comment: @P.Salmon, I need to get records in which the total number of records by VIN code is 3 : count (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) and other params from my request

Comment: @Akina, the same for date_reg_first and location

Comment: You may, for example, add a condition `.. AND NOT EXIST ({subquery which selects the rows with the same VIN and a column value not in list})`.

Comment: @Akina, for example? Can you provide full sql ? Thanks

Comment: @Akina , for some reasons in the year can be strings

Comment: *Final list need contains only this VIN: XTA111930B0149393 and have a 3 record with id: 38483146, 98294552 and 112853476* Why? Another 3 rows matches the conditions it seems.. or I don't see something?

Comment: @Akina, because I need only records which have only these conditions:
AND `date_reg_first` IN (0,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `date_reg_last` IN (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) 
and have count (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) - 3 records in total by VIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `ac_gibdd_shortinfo` t0
WHERE `vin` LIKE 'XTA%' 
  AND `model` LIKE '%1119%' 
  AND `date_reg_first` IN (0,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `date_reg_last` IN (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `year` LIKE '2011' 
  AND `location` IN ('УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.','С РУНГА')
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM ac_gibdd_shortinfo t1
                   WHERE t0.vin = t1.vin
                     AND t1.date_reg_first NOT IN (0,1506715200,1555963200) )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM ac_gibdd_shortinfo t2
                   WHERE t0.vin = t2.vin
                     AND t2.date_reg_last NOT IN (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM ac_gibdd_shortinfo t3
                   WHERE t0.vin = t3.vin
                     AND t3.location NOT IN ('УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.','С РУНГА') )
```

PS. According indices will improve.

---

> and have count (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) - 3 records in total by VIN – blood73

```sql
SELECT vin, model, date_reg_first, date_reg_last, `year`, location 
FROM `ac_gibdd_shortinfo` t0
WHERE `vin` LIKE 'XTA%' 
  AND `model` LIKE '%1119%' 
  AND `date_reg_first` IN (0,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `date_reg_last` IN (1306440000,1506715200,1555963200) 
  AND `year` LIKE '2011' 
  AND `location` IN ('УЛЬЯНОВСК Г.','С РУНГА')
  AND 3 = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM ac_gibdd_shortinfo t1
            WHERE t0.vin = t1.vin );
```

Comment: Thank you. This query return XTA111930B0149393 records (correct) and XTA111930B0156231 (not correct, because have only one record in table (need 3 ) )

Comment: @blood73 Updated. But the table may contain, for example, 3 duplicated rows with the same values - and they matches all your conditions and will be returned which seems to be incorrect to you... Take this into account and add according constraint (unique index by `(vin, ???)`).

Comment: I don't have duplicate rows. For example, XTA111930B0149393 and  date_reg_last =  1306440000 is one row, XTA111930B0149393 and  date_reg_last =  1506715200 is another row

Comment: @blood73 I'd prefer to create unique index by `(vin, date_reg_last)` for to guarantee this uniqueness.